# Error while running code containing equation

Tags: equations

```
\underline{y}={(y_{111}&plus;y_{112}&plus;...&plus;y_{ijk})}^{T}
```

! Missing $ inserted.

```
                $
l.97 ...i, B = j, C = k and let \underline{y}={(y_
                                                  {111}&plus;y_{112}&plus;.....
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. This fragment of code isn't very useful. Apparently you have forgottten `\begin{align}...\end{align}` around the `equation`, but this is only a guess -- without any further information

Comment: try remove braces `={` end`}^`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I don't know much about latex. Should we start an equation with \begin{align}?

Comment: @touhami, I tried removing the braces.still it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sana: Since you have `&` (which are alignment characters): in this case yes

Comment: as @ChristianHupfer said with this one line of code we can not do any thing helpful.

Comment: Those ampersands have nothing to do with alignment, they are simply remains of the plus sign.

Comment: @Sana, ideally, post [a minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), which is basically your whole document, but stripped down to the actual problem you're encountering.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if this is the output you are looking for, but here is my interpretation:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Foo bar baz. Foo bar baz. Foo bar baz. Foo bar baz. Foo bar baz. Foo bar baz. Foo bar baz. %
$\underline{y}=(y_\mathrm{111}+y_\mathrm{112}+\dots +y_\mathrm{ijk})^{T}$ %
Foo bar baz. Foo bar baz. Foo bar baz. Foo bar baz. Foo bar baz. Foo bar baz. Foo bar baz.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You do know that `plus;` does look strange, don't you? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I want an output which somewhat resembles the above stated one except that instead of plus i want + sign and excluding the ; symbol.

Comment: And also I am writing this equation within a sentence.

Comment: @Sana: runartrollet tried to make working code out of your fragment of non-working, er, say, 'code'. `+` and `-` are possible in LaTeX directly, there's no need of writing `plus` (apart from being wrong anyway here). You've shown a one-liner of code which does not reveal really what you want to achieve.

Comment: yep, I just assumed if I changed `plus`it would be wrong anyway, so I saw no reason to give more guesswork.

Comment: Then you probably like to write `some text $\underline{y}=(y_{111} + y_{112} + \dots  + y_{ijk})^{T}$ and more text` (based on guessing). It seems that you need to read some basic introduction to the LaTeX.